# Sound indicator shows as muted in 13.10

Tags: sound, indicator

As in the title, what has happened to it? Not that it is not working, albeit it is sort of annoying seeing that your computer's volume is allegedly muted when it is not at all. Please see the image below - this is how it looks like. There is no menu when I left click on it.

Screenshot:

[image: Sound indicator]

Thanks for any kind of help,

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me.

I fixed it running this command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall indicator-sound*
```